# How do I combine these three regex into one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression that only accepts:

Min 100 and atleast 1000 characters, characters “,’,<,> aren't allowed, two full stops one after another aren't allowed.

This is what I have for now:

- `^.{100,1000}$` → for 100 to 1000 characters
- `^[^"'<>]*$` → for the characters that aren't allowed
- `^([^._]|[.](?=[^.]|$)|_(?=[^_]|$))*$` → doesn't allow 2 consecutive dots

How do I combine this regex into one? ._.

Comment: Why does the OP want to (forcibly) combine it when the result is going to be even more difficult to read than already the one which does not allow 2 consecutive dots? Why not working with two patterns one for the 100 to 1000 characters and a separate dot test?

Comment: @PeterSeliger just one more question, '^[^"'<>]*$' -> im having trouble with this one since it has the symbol " in it, my javascript thinks i should close the " and it keeps showing me an error for it. How do I fix it?

Comment: I've managed to combine them, thats the only problem i have left.

Comment: @Zoof at the third point you described that it doesn't allow 2 consecutive dots but it also does checks for underscore (`_`)

Comment: So what does it check exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part `[^._]` means no dot or underscore and this part `[.](?=[^.]|$)|_(?=[^_]|$)` matches either a `.` or `_` followed by the opposite or end of string.

You could write the pattern using a single negative lookahead assertion excluding `__` or `..`

```
^(?!.*([._])\1)[^"'<>\n]{100,1000}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what is at the right is not

  - `.*([._])\1` capture either `.` or `_` and match the same captured char after it *(meaning no occurrence of `..` or `__`)*
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^"'<>\n]{100,1000}` Match 100-1000 times any character except the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZGAsV/1) (with the quantifier set to `{10,100}` for the demo)